# show complete hovering data as an alert message when clicking on any child container

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

The query is that when I click on any child container, hovering data that appear should also appear as an alert message as a complete hovering text.
'''

```
  indicator = px.treemap(filtered_df,
                color=COLOR,
                color_continuous_scale=color_discrete_map,
                # path = PATH, 
                path = ['Sector','Symbol','dailyChange',], 
                # path = ['Sector','Symbol','dailyChange','Market Capitalization','PE Ratio%'],
                
               
                
                # template='plotly_white',
                maxdepth=6,
                hover_data=HOVER_DATA, 
                values=value_attribute, 
                custom_data=HOVER_DATA,
                color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

    indicator.update_traces(textfont_size=22,)
```

'''

[[image: this is my home page, showing container here]]

[[image: here hovering data which appears on right that, same hovering content should appear in above alert message.]]

Comment: i am assuming this is done in plotly dash. can you include more of your code so your app is reproducible? what part of your app is the child container?